# SAS: Condense separate measurement variables across category

Tags: sas, transform, transpose

I have a data set whose variables represent two kinds of information: a variable measurement and a category.

For instance, `Var1A` measures the first variable (eg. blood pressure) of Category A (eg. male/female) whereas `Var2B` measures the second variable (eg. heart rate) of Category B (eg. male/female).

```
Key Var1A Var2A Var1B Var2B
--- ----- ----- ----- -----
002   1     2     3     4
031   5     6     7     8
028   9     10    11    12
```

I need each measurement variable to be condensed across the category type.

```
Key Type Var1 Var2
--- ---- ---- ----
002   A    1    2
002   B    3    4
028   A    9    10
028   B    11   12
031   A    5    6
031   B    7    8
```

The sorting of the condensed data set is unimportant to me.

---

What I have come up with works and yields the data sets seen above.   I basically brute forced/fiddled my way to this solution.  However, I wonder if there is a more direct/intuitive way to do it, possibly without needing to sort first and drop so many variables.

```
data have;
  input key $ @@  Var1A Var2A Var1B Var2B;

  datalines;
  002 1 2   3   4
  031 5 6   7   8
  028 9 10  11  12
  ;
run;

proc sort data = have out = step1_sort;
  by key;
run;

proc transpose data = step1_sort out = step2_transpose;
  by key;
run;

data step3_assign_type_and_variable (drop = _NAME_);
  set step2_transpose ;

  if      _NAME_ = 'Var1A' then do;
      variable = 'Var1';
      type = 'A';
    end;
  else if _NAME_ = 'Var1B' then do;
      variable = 'Var1';
      type = 'B';
    end;
  else if _NAME_ = 'Var2A' then do;
      variable = 'Var2';
      type = 'A';
    end;
  else if _NAME_ = 'Var2B' then do;
      variable = 'Var2';
      type = 'B';
    end;
run;

proc transpose  data = step3_assign_type_and_variable 
                out  = step4_get_want (drop = _NAME_);
  var col1;
  by key type;
  id variable;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the same method except replacing your brute force with cleaner substrings:

```
** use this step to replace your brute force code **;
data step3_assign_type_and_variable; set step2_transpose;
    type = upcase(substr(_name_,length(_name_),1));
    variable = propcase(substr(_name_,1,4));
    drop _name_;
run;
```